# Why is the node version in my ssh-action for Github Actions not updating?

Tags: node.js, git, github, ssh, action

I am trying to deploy my next.js application on my VPS when there is a push on the production branch on my repo, but the SSH script is failing because the node.js version is stuck on v12.22.9, even though I specify in the main.yml to use node 18.x using actions/setup-node@v3.3.0.

My main.yml file:

```yaml
name: Deploy

# Controls when the action will run. 
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ production ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - name: Use Node.js 18
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3.3.0
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: Deploy using ssh
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USER }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: 22
          script: |
            node -v
            ./deploy-landing.sh
```

The sh file has all of the install and deployment commands, and when the job runs, these are the errors:

```
out: v12.22.9
...
err: npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
err: npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'next@13.4.8',
err: npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=16.8.0' },
err: npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
err: npm WARN EBADENGINE }
...
out: > next build
err: /var/www/landing/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:435
err:                     ...pageKeys.app ?? []
```

Answer (score 1):

I added these two lines to the top of my .sh file:

```bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use 18
```

And the node version properly updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem: the `appleboy/ssh-action` action executes its `script` command(s) *on the remote host* and not in the GHA container (which has a fresh, unused, node v18 instance). You should be able to SSH onto the remote host and get an identical result by executing `node -v`.

Comment: I see, but how should I attempt to fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the contents of your `deploy-landing.sh` script to give a real answer, sorry. In general, though, I'd either do as much of that script as possible in the container itself (using `shell: bash` instead of a specific action), or I'd remove the unused `actions/setup-node` and have that script install the correct version on the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me

```
 - name: Deploy using ssh
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.USER }}
      key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      port: 22
      script: |
        sudo npm cache clean -f
        sudo npm install -g n
        sudo n stable
        node -v
```